# What would be a good design to achieve this synchronization across machines..?

Tags: java, process, synchronization, atomic

I have 2 machines both running one process each. shell process on Machine A will scp something to machine B, and java process on B will use these files. Both processes run as crontab tasks.

How to achieve synchronization/atomicity etc? How to signal that whole of file has been written.

so that process on B always has access to latest and complete files, the handler doesn't go stale..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a filesystem with atomic moves you can do that. Or use symbolic links.

A copies the file to a temp location on B. When the upload is complete, it relocates, with a move or symlink, the file into the expected location. B can then only ever see completely uploaded files.

If your process on A cannot SSH into B to make the final move, it could rather add another, zero byte marker file which indicates the upload is complete.

A uploads FOO.txt, when that upload is complete, it creates the FOO.txt.done file. B then scans the directory for *.done files, and uses the associated data file. Plus cleanup of course.

Comment: Can the process on A do these atomic moves on B machine?

Comment: Updated to say you could SSH to do the move, or use a marker file to indicate completion.

Comment: if you remember it off the top of your head, what is the command to make the move using ssh?

Comment: `ssh user@host 'mv /path/a /path/b'` :)

Comment: and this move is guaranteed to be atomic..? even over ssh? I mean, ssh makes sure that it is atomic?

Comment: No, SSH merely provides the access to the machine. The atomicity of the move will be dependent upon the filesystem and layout. For example, if the two paths reside on different slices then it'll require a copy, which will certainly not be atomic. You could create a symlink which is almost guaranteed to be atomic, AFAIK. `ln -s /path/a /path/b`. Your cleanup code would need to take this into account though.

Comment: As a follow-up of this, if the process on B will have handle to the old file, which will be replaced by a new file by this move by process on A. So will this handle continue to work? (i.e. I want this handle to work as per previous version of the file) and from next crontab on, IW ant to work it on new latest version of file..

Comment: The assumption here is that the process B is not aware of the new files until the process A has moved/linked the file into place. Process A cannot know when process B has finished with a previous upload, thus process B should manage removal of completed jobs. Process A just copies files to B and then moves them into a place that B looks at when it's run. B processes the job and probably moves the file to some "complete" folder when done. Process C archives the jobs. Don't "replace" files, that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4781/discussion-between-p2pnode-and-ptomli)

Answer (score 0):

A quick'n'dirty work around / solution for the problem could be resolved by using user control, setting the ownership (and chmod'ing appropriately) when copying the file (using SCP from A), when finishing then changing the ownership / permissions so that the process on B will be able to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

A few hacks that I can suggest I guess. You can either :-

1. create a temp file (like a lock file) at the start of file writing, the presence of which means that the file being streamed is being written to and delete the temp file once the writing is complete. 
   OR
2. Remove crontab on the consumer process and have the scp process send a signal (JMS/ unicast). The java process could just be a listener on a queue/ socket or be invoked upon receiving a unicast.